# What is the word to describe someone who thrives on change?

Tags: single-word-requests

Need word that would describe this type of person and I am unable to locate it. Please help! I was recently ask for a word to describe myself and the best thing I could come up with is I thrive on change, but it is multiple words and I was asked to narrow it down to one. Therefore, I have been reaching out to determine if someone out there might know a word that works. My apologies for having the incorrect format for questions.

Comment: Please include a sample sentence where you could use this new word.

Comment: Flexible.  Adventurous.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to EL&U. The nearest I can come to is the word **neophile** derived from [Neophilia](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/neophilia) defined by the Merriam Webster online dictionary as

> love of or enthusiasm for what is new or novel

Neophile does not have a separate entry in the MW dictionary but it is listed as a word derived from it.

Neophile may not be quite the word you are looking for but is the nearest I can think of. If someone else comes up with a better one I will be interested to see it.